# Почему падает производительность со временем выполнения задачи

Tags: java

Есть код, который из fb2 файлов преобразует файлы в txt. Я запускаю процесс в 4-х потоках. Сначала, все довольно быстро считает(10 файлов секунд за 5), а потом скорость все меньше и меньше становится. В чем может быть проблема?

```
public class Converter {
    TaskManager taskManager = new TaskManager(4);
    public void start(File f, String path){
        taskManager.start();
        dirToTxt(f, path);
    }
    private void dirToTxt(File f, String dir2) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = f.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                dirToTxt(file,dir2);
            }
        } else {
            Task task = new Task(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        DocumentParser documentParser = new DocumentParser(f);
                        Document document = documentParser.parseDocument();
                        DefaultFb2 fb2 = new DefaultFb2(document);
                        fb2.saveAsTxt(dir2);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
            };
            taskManager.addTask(task);
        }
    }
}

public class TaskManager {
    int threadscount;
    Thread[] threads;
    TaskBuffer taskBuffer = new TaskBuffer();
    boolean isWorking = false;
    public TaskManager(int threadscount){
        this.threadscount = threadscount;
        threads = new Thread[threadscount];
        for(int i = 0;i<threadscount;i++){
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (isWorking){
                        taskBuffer.getTask().run();
                        if(taskBuffer.getSize()<1)isWorking=false;
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        }catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    private void _run(){
        for (int i = 0;i<threadscount;i++){
            threads[i].start();
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        Thread chkThread = new Thread(new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!isWorking){
                    try {
                        if (taskBuffer.getSize() > 0) {
                            isWorking = true;
                            _run();
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
                }
            }
        });
        chkThread.start();
    }

    public void addTask(Task t){
        taskBuffer.addTask(t);
    }

}
```

P.S. Также в пике может занимать память до 1гига. Хотя абсолютно непонятно откуда...
Также количество памяти сильно не меняется при запуске 1 или 20 потоков

Comment: может папки `.` и `..` зацикливаются?

Comment: @Saidolim нет, специально положил все в одну папочку, чтобы можно было адекватно оценить скорость

Comment: ИМХО, сборщик мусора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы понять, на что расходуется память - необходимо выполнить "профилирование"!

И не стоит нагромождать конструкторы, лучше создать метод инит и вызывать его в начале метода старт, хоть в Вашем случае это не критично, но все же, в большинстве случаев, это плохая практика и не стоит к ней привыкать.

П. С. Я не очень вникал в Ваш код, но мне кажется, что создается слишком много потоков. Меня смущает вызов из цикла в отдельном потоке, метода, в котором используется цикл для запуска потоков.